# What is the ActiveModel method attribute "_was" used for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

When using autocomplete in the console, I often see "`_was`" postpended to my attributes. But I can't find any documentation or best practices for usage. What does it do and how should it be used?

Example: `user.fname` has the method `user.fname_was`

Using source_location, I've tracked it down to: active_model/attribute_methods.rb", line 296 but there isn't anything specific.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That is a part of ActiveModel::Dirty
You can see it here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/af64ac4e5ce8406137d5520fa88e8f652ab703e9/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb#L146
Example

```
person = Person.find_by_name('Uncle Bob')
person.changed?       # => false
```

Change the name:

```
person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed?       # => true
person.name_changed?  # => true

#method _was return prev attribute value
person.name_was  # => 'Uncle Bob'  
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bob']
person.name = 'Bill'
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bill']
```

Comment: just was playing with it few months ago, I was digging in source code

Comment: I would also note that calling `person.save!` will reset `name_was` to be the same as the new `name`